# Besides web, which tool I can browse files from git?

Tags: git

I am coming from Perforce. It allows me to browse the files stored in the server by using p4v. I am wondering if there is similar GUI tool for git.

Answer (score 0):

With git, there's really no need for such a tool. Just fetch changes from the server and browse locally.

Comment: My local files may different from servers.

Comment: Then you just add each of those servers as a remote and fetch from all of them.

Comment: If I just want to checkout only a specific directory, what should I do?

Comment: Do you mean only fetch a specific directory from a remote? Newer versions of git have "sparse checkout" which might help. This [blog post](http://jasonkarns.com/blog/subdirectory-checkouts-with-git-sparse-checkout/) gives some more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to *see* files instead of checking them out, you can use `git show ${revision}:path/to/file`, where ${revision} could be a commit id, a branch name, a tag name...

You can install and use [`tig`](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/), too, which is a curses client for `git`. Typing <kbd>t</kbd> you can browse the tree a commit refers.

Finally, you can just checkout a file/directory from a given revision, but that would of course make your working directory to differ from the index. You can do this via `git checkout ${revision} -- path/to/file`.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should just check out the revision you want to look at, by using `git checkout %revision%`. If that is too slow you are probably doing something wrong ;).

To look at a specific file in a given revision, use `git show %revision%:filename`. This also works for looking at directories, e.g. `git show head^:./`

If you want a gui for doing this, use the included `git gui`. `Repository > Browse Branch` files is what you’re looking for.